# Coldfusion cfquery realtime cfprogressbar

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, coldfusion-11, cfquery

My function running query, its taking sometime depending on requested data. While query running, I want to show real query loading cfprogressbar & changing status/title while cfprogressbar doing progress. im still searching on google till now no luck all examples showing static time.

I was thinking if i can get real cfquery loading time & i'll pass that value to cfprogressbar. Please advise

- coldfusion 11
- windows 2012
- cfprogressbar
- cfquery

Comment: The cfprogressbar tag is to display the data it binds to, so, where are you going to get the 'get real cfquery loading time' thing from? Is your server side code providing this somewhere?

Comment: this is what i want to know ? if im running query if it taking time can i show progbar?

Comment: coldfusion engine does not run your query, the db server runs your query and for that reason the coldfusion engine does not know where your db server is at while running the query, the coldfusion engine made a request to your db server and is waiting for the db server to respond

Comment: you are absolutely  cfquery tag request to db server ..  my question is when cfquery tag request to dbserver for recordset. while dbserver processing  that query, if that query taking time can i show progbar?

Comment: Does your db engine tell to the coldfusion engine from time to time how much time is left until it finishes and sends back the respones? NO. So you can't show an accurate progress bar. You can show a 'spinner' if you want to let your user know that something is going on.

Comment: @TechMark2K is correct.  ColdFusion only knows when it started the request but it will never know how long the request will be to the DB server, so therefore it is not possible to give an accurate progress bar.  Think of it this way, the clock starts and CF knows how long it has been running, but not for how long it will run.  That is why you can't do a progress bar. The only thing you can do is have a spinner.

Comment: A query will continue to execute, whether or not the user navigates away from the page. So unless there is a reason they must wait, rather than showing an indeterminate status, it might be better handled as a job/background task. Present a list of jobs. Allow a user to kick off a specific job. Then check periodically for job completion and/or current running time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't show an accurate progress bar. The ColdFusion engine does not run your query, the database server runs your query and for that reason the ColdFusion engine does not know where your db server is at while running the query. You can show a 'spinner' if you want to let your user know that something is going on.

Comment: Agreed. Your [initial comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090518/coldfusion-cfquery-realtime-cfprogressbar#comment59840338_36090518) put it pretty succinctly: *"Does your db engine tell to the coldfusion engine from time to time how much time is left until it finishes and sends back the responses? NO.* ie Therefore, you cannot show exact progress. Only some sort of indeterminate status indicator to let the user know something is happening .. but not specifics like how much longer until the task finishes.